# how to insert date in mysql using jsp?

Tags: java

this is my edited code...

```
         java.sql.Timestamp sqlNow = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

                stmt = con.createStatement();
    //stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO cregn values('"+appno+"','"+usname+"','"+upwd +"','"+fname+"','"+mname+"','"+lname+"','"+dob+"','"+gend+"','"+faname+"','"+saddr+"','"+caddr+"','"+staddr +"','"+pin+"','"+cno+"','"+email+"','"+occ+"','"+secques+"','"+answer+"','Processing','"+sqlNow+"')");
                pst = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cregn (aplno, username, pwd, firstname,middlename,lastname, dob,gender, fathername, street,city,state, pincode, phone, email,occupation,secques,answer,dor)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                pst.setInt(1, appno);
                pst.setString(2, usname);
                pst.setString(3, upwd);
                pst.setString(4, fname);
                pst.setString(5, mname);
                pst.setString(6, lname);
                pst.setString(7, dob);
                pst.setString(8, gend);
                pst.setString(9, faname);
                pst.setString(10, saddr);
                pst.setString(11, caddr);
                pst.setString(12, staddr);
                pst.setString(13, pin);
                pst.setString(14, cno);
                pst.setString(15, email);
                pst.setString(16, occ);
                // pst.setString(17,ph);
                pst.setString(17, secques);
                pst.setString(18, answer);

                pst.setTimestamp(19, sqlNow);

                pst.executeUpdate();

                out.println("Registration Successful for application " + appno);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                out.println("Invalid Data! All fields are mandatory..." + ee.getMessage());
            }


%>
```

after executing this code error displayed  "Invalid Data! All fields are mandatory..data truncation"

Comment: Did you execute the statement, I mean, INSERT one?

Comment: yes, i am excuting the insert statement using prepared statement.

Comment: Is auto commit set to false, if yes, then you even need to commit the transaction?

Comment: @TulsiHemrajani: *"yes, i am excuting the insert statement using prepared statement"* Not in the code you've shown you're not. If you really are, *show that code*.

Answer (score 3):

You are not executing the statement.

You need to call executeUpdate

Answer (score 2):

You have to call [`execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29) or [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) on `pst` in order to actually do the work. E.g., at the end:

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

All that the code you've shown does is *prepare* the statement for execution, it doesn't execute it. This is one of the main differences between `PreparedStatement` and `Statement`. In `Statement`, you pass the SQL to execute directly into `executeUpdate` (as seen in your commented-out line using `stmt`). With a `PreparedStatement`, you supply the SQL with `?` as you've done, set those parameters, and *then* call `executeUpdate` (or `execute`), which you haven't done.

Comment: after using this statement :pst.excuteUpdate();.... and running the code it is showing..."Invalid Data all fields are mandatory.....Data Truncation:out of range value adjusted for colmn "phone" at row 1". data size of col phone is 20 in database....

Comment: @TulsiHemrajani: Good, now you're executing the statement! :-) The truncation thing is a completely different problem. It means that your `cno` variable has a value that's more than 20 characters long (as `phone` is the 14th thing in your `INSERT`, and `cno` is the variable you're using for parameter #14 (`pst.setString(14,cno );`).

Comment: yes ,, cno variable that is  20 characters long. and phone is the 14th thing in the INSERT .. i am inserting a phone cno which is 10 characters long... still the same error is displayed  "Invalid Data all fields are mandatory.....Data Truncation:out of range value adjusted for colmn "phone" at row 1"

Comment: @TulsiHemrajani: *"...Invalid Data all fields are mandatory..."* Well, I'm not seeing anywhere that you're supplying parameter #19, for instance. (You jump from 18 to 20.) Just step back and look closely at the code, this is basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `executeUpdate()` being called on `pst`.

Answer (score 0):

use `pst.executeUpdate();` to execute the query and make sure that in transaction use `setAutoCommit(true)` has to be called.